# According to Newton's third law, why don't Action and Reaction make equilibrium?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

According to Newton's third law, Action and Reaction are equal and in opposite direction.
If both forces are equal and in opposite direction then why they don't make equilibrium and void the effect of force?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45653/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the forces act on different objects. If you write it as $F_{AB}=-F_{BA}$, the first term is object $A$ acting on $B$ and vice versa for the second.