# Newton's third law confusion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

[image]

If A exerts a force of 200N on B, then by newton's third law, 200N would be exerted on it. Similarly, if B exerts 100N on A, by newton's third law, 100N would be exerted on it. Therefore the net forces acting on both would be 300N in opposite directions. In this case how would A accelerate forward?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [With Newton's third law, why are things capable of moving?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45653/)

Comment: I'm not saying they won't move. I'm asking why they both wouldn't move in opposite directions with 300/M acceleration.

Comment: @lemon its a completely different question please look closer into it. In this, hand A is exerting 200N and hand B 100N

Comment: No it's the *same* question, just formulated in terms of two hands pushing against each other rather than a finger versus friction acting on a matchbox. The physics is the same.