# Does Newton's 3rd law of motion apply when a person is standing still on a ground?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram

When a person is standing still, the action of the Earth on their body is a gravitational force. What is the reaction force?  Is it the person's weight acting on the Earth?

Comment: Yes It called normal force. Its an electromagnetic force. Read resnick halliday for details.

Comment: The normal force of the ground on the person **is not** the third law reaction to the gravitational force.   Reaction forces are always of the same type.  In this case: the Earth pulls gravitationally on the person, the person pulls gravitationally on the Earth.

Comment: @Prathyush Makes a common mistake.  PaulT  is correct.  I emphasize this for any novices who might be reading.

Comment: @PaulT. is correct my bad. I got confused.

Comment: related http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45653/

Answer (score 2):

## Newton's third law applied to gravity

Newton's 3rd law is **always** true in classical physics.  For a person standing on the ground the Earth pulls on the person with gravity, so the person pulls on the the Earth with gravity.  3rd law force pairs are always of the same type (in this case gravity) and always act on different objects.  For your example one acts on the person, and the other acts on the Earth.

$$ \vec{F}_\mathrm{Earth\rightarrow person} = -
\vec{F}_\mathrm{person\rightarrow Earth} \quad (3^\mathrm{rd}\,\mathrm{law})$$

## What about the normal force?

The normal force pushing up on the person prevents them from falling.  This force contributes to the **net force** acting on the person.  To understand it we must consider **Newton's 2nd law**, $\vec{F}_\mathrm{net} = m \vec{a}$.  If the person is not accelerating, they have zero net force acting on them.  All of the forces in a Newton's 2nd law statement act on the same object.

$$ \vec{F}_\mathrm{Earth\rightarrow person} +  \vec{N}_\mathrm{ground\rightarrow person} = m_\mathrm{person}\, \vec{a}_\mathrm{person} = 0 $$

$$ \vec{F}_\mathrm{Earth\rightarrow person} = - \vec{N}_\mathrm{ground\rightarrow person} \quad (2^\mathrm{nd}\,\mathrm{law})$$

The equality of the normal force and the gravitational force depends on there being **zero acceleration**.  If the person is accelerating, then the normal force is not equal to the gravitational force.  You can experience this at the start or end of an elevator ride, when you speed up and slow down.

By Newton's third law the ground pushes with a normal force on the person, so the person pushes with a normal force on the ground.

$$ \vec{N}_\mathrm{ground\rightarrow person} = -\vec{N}_\mathrm{person\rightarrow ground} \quad (3^\mathrm{rd}\,\mathrm{law})$$

It's worth noting that the name 'normal force' refers to forces that push perpendicularly to a surface.  'Normal' is a mathy word for perpendicular.  The ground pushes perpendicularly relative to the surface of contact (the person's feet).  Anytime you push on something, you apply a normal force to the surface.

Comment: The third law is not *always* true.     In the conventional statement it is violated in  Lorentz force interactions, notably the force between two moving charged particles.    However, the more "important", and more general law, conservation of momentum, does hold for electromagnetic interactions once you include the momentum of the field itself.  I don't know how one would modify the conventional statement of the third law to cover electromagnetic interactions, as it introduces a third entity, the field.

Comment: True... I added a `classical physics' caveat.  Although, that seems above the scope of this question.

Comment: I agree that the details are out of scope, but a novice reading this might glom on to the word *always*.     I don't think "classical" is quite the right restriction, as it can be argued that field energy/momentum is classical.  The third law fails for the Lorentz force even at low speed.  Maybe "Newtonian (i.e., mechanical, not including electromagnetic interactions)"  would be a better restriction?

Comment: @garyp - That's right. The electromagnetic field is also classical. What about the 3rd law in the case of a classical field force?

Comment: @freecharly Third law is basically equivalent to momentum conservation. So if you have a system has a translation in-variance you can look the the no-ether charge corresponding to translation invariance. I am not sure about this with out doing the calculation involved, but you maybe able to rewrite this in a force form.

Comment: @Prathyush - So you say  that the momentum imparted to a particle by a classical field exerting a force $\vec F=d\vec P/dt$ is mirrored by a negative momentum change of the classical field which should correspond to a force $-\vec F$ on the field. Thus the 3rd law seems to hold also in this case

Comment: @freecharly Yes that is what I had in mind. However I have not done any examples. There maybe be subtleties that emerge when you work out the details. I cannot see anything strange happening when you talk about interaction between fields and fields, however point particles are singular objects, and there may be subtleties that may emerge in such cases.