# How can any object move?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

If an object A exerts a force on another object B, an equal and opposite force will be applied on object A by object B, so that means for a force to be applied on object B by object A, a force must have been applied on object A itself, so when object B exerts a reaction force on object A, the net force on object A will be "0" and object A will not move but object B will. If this is so then how will walking be possible? Because when we push the ground, it pushes back to cancel the force we are already applying on the ground.

Comment: An object does not feel the force it exerts itself. As you say: "*...for a force to be applied on object B **by** object A...*" Object B feels this force, *not* object A. Object A only feels the reaction force, which is then not balanced out.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45653/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

**The forces are applied on different bodies.**

When you walk, you push the ground. This causes the ground to move (of course, by $F=ma$, $m$ is the mass of the Earth and so the force you exert on it has negligible effect). Against that, the force the ground exerts on you acts on your much-smaller mass, and that's why you move.