# According to newton's third law "for every force there is an equal and opposite reaction" then explain how our our arms move?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

[image]

My biceps muscles are attached to my arms bone/bones through a tendon/tendons, if my biceps pulls my arms bone/bones with a force of 100N upwards then my arms bone/bones pushes back downwards with a force of -100N,therefore fnet should be 0 and there should be no movement, however in reality our arm moves upwards, why?

Comment: Please improve your drawing and re-post, it's not understandable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given Newton's third law, why are things capable of moving?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45653/)

Comment: @Sandejo,it is somehow similiar but it didn't answer my question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106973/discussion-on-question-by-zheer-according-to-newtons-third-law-for-every-force).