# Newton 3rd law confusion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

Why do things even move? I mean based on Newton 3rd law no matter how much force you exert on an object, it will always exert an equal and opposite force back to you. So why do things move?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given Newton's third law, why are things capable of moving?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45653/)

Answer (score 1):

The forces are exerted on **different** objects. If **you** hit a ball, the ball will apply an equal and opposite force on **you**.

The force you apply is **exerted on the ball**.

The force the ball applies is **exerted on you**.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a classic example that addresses your question.  A horse pulls on a cart, so the cart fulls with an equal and opposite force on the horse.  The horse "says" since these forces are equal and opposite, I cannot move the cart, so put me up and let me sleep:)

There is an unbalanced force *on the cart* from the horse, so the cart accelerates.  The force of the cart *on the horse* has no effect on the motion of the cart.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a sled with a load, being pushed on a level surface.

Exerting a force on the object, requires (as the object moves) that I
walk with it, else the moving object leaves my force-exerting hands
and the force drops to zero.

Forces can make an object move, is the definition of 'force'; we get
a measure of force by watching motion.  We also have to exert a
force against the ground under our feet, when we follow that object,
and the forces of foot pushing back and hand pushing forward BOTH
act on me as I push the sled.

On a slippery ice field, with no other force than the hand-sled interaction,
the motion might not be useful, but both the sled, and I, would move.
Why would one expect otherwise?