# Is there an opposing force to each force, if so wouldn't they cancel each other out, making the NetForce=0?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, equilibrium

Is there an opposing force to each force? If so, wouldn't they just cancel each other out thus net force being zero?
The idea of opposing forces just confuse me. I know that I am probably missing some key information. This has been bugging me throughout my high school career.

edit: [Given Newton's third law, why are things capable of moving?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45653/given-newtons-third-law-why-are-things-capable-of-moving) answers from there has helped me understand it. I don't want to delete my question since it has answers but know that my situation is resolved, still I appreciate you giving me your time by answering.

Answer (score 0):

The forces are acting on different bodies. For example, Suppose you push a car then you are applying a force on a car and an opposite force act on you by the car.

Similar example, Can be gravitational force, earth pulling you and you pulling the earth toward you. SIMILARLY, For coulomb force.

Answer (score 0):

According to Newton's third law there is an opposite action for every action. These two actions activate on two bodies. If you try to push the wall with a hand, there is a force on the wall by hand ($F_{WH}$) and the opposing force is on your hand by the wall ($F_{HW}$). If you consider the hand and the wall in the same system, they are internal forces, so the net force is zero. If you consider the hand and the wall as seperated systems they are external forces.