# The Newton's third law and spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image]

According to the picture above,when the restoring force pull the block, the block is also stretching the spring , so the spring should not restore. Well I am totally confused with this question . Help me find out the answer Please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given Newton's third law, why are things capable of moving?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45653/given-newtons-third-law-why-are-things-capable-of-moving)

Answer (score 0):

When thinking about Newton's third law, you mustn't think that the action and re-action nullify each other, because they are acting upon different bodies. You have to consider how each force independently affects the body it is acting upon. In the case of the block on the spring, there is only one force acting on the block, which is the restoring force, so the block is going to move as there is no other force holding it back.