# If net force applied by my hand to box is contact force then shouldn't the box apply same magnitude of contact force on my hand?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

Wait,what I mean here is,if I applied contact force with my hand and it pushed the box,then the box,as said in 3rd law,should push my hand with same contact force.

The point is,if **net force** applied by my hand to box is **contact force** then shouldn't the box apply same magnitude of **contact force** on my hand?(same kind of forces they are **(pairs)** aren't they?

Please explain it....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given Newton's third law, why are things capable of moving?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45653/)

Comment: Actually I did see it but it didn't answer my question as I described in the body.