# What type of force is applied to an object when we push it? I am talking about the net force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

what I mean...
If **net force** applied by my hand to box is **contact force** then should not the box apply same magnitude of **contact force** on my hand and the box will remain still [These forces are in pair,aren`t they?

Comment: you are new to the site . One does not repeat a closed or duplicated question. One edits the closed or duplicated answer to show some thought on why it is  not a duplicate. If you read the answer to the question listed as duplicate you should see that if you take in all the forces that apply to the problem , there is extra force on the object. Think  a simpler example.  Two balls on ice, no friction, hitting each other. Both will move .

Comment: Related recent post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/725116/2451