Tug of war and Newton's third law. How to break static state of physical system "two teams-rope"?
Consider tug of war from physical point of view.
We have physical system "two teams-rope".
Let first team can pull the rope with 240N maximum force and second team can pull the rope with 280N force.
If two teams pull the rope with 240N force then we have static state of physical system "two teams-rope".
My questions are:

How to break static state of physical system "two teams-rope"?

What will happen if the second team will pull the rope with 250N force in static state?



To break force equilibrium- increase one of teams pull force. If you will add $10N$ for the second team,- equilibrium will be broken and second team will win.

@AgniusVasiliauskas In this case the third law of motion is violated. How is it possible?

Mike, there is not only the pulling force on the rope. Without the force on the floor, no tug of war would be possible. Try to re-analyze the problem by considering the force on the floor of the two teams.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I know about force on the floor. But if the first team can pull the rope with 240N maximum force then how is it possible that second team can pull the rope with 250N force?

Indeed, it is not possible. What matters is the resulting force when you consider all the forces. You may find useful this link https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45653/given-newtons-third-law-why-are-things-capable-of-moving
